# ¿Respaldar contenido de un BD en /data/data/package/databases/nombredb.db en sdcard?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Mi aplicacion crea un db, lo que deseo hacer es un backup de lo que contiene entonces hago el siguiente codigo:

```
  File CarFile = new File("sdcard/xxxx");
    if (!CarFile.exists()) {
        try {
            CarFile.mkdir();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    File f=new File("/data/data/x.x.x/databases/xxx.db");
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    FileOutputStream fos=null;

    try
    {
        fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        fos=new FileOutputStream("sdcard/xxxx/xxx.sql");
        while(true)
        {
            int i=fis.read();
            if(i!=-1)
            {fos.write(i);}
            else
            {break;}
        }
        fos.flush();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {}
    }
```

pero el código que obtengo no es legible en un editor de texto y ningún gestor de sqlite.

Comment: Y no puedes nisiquiera ponerlo aqui, o colocar una captura de pantalla.

Comment: no me queda muy claro porque si tu archivo es un .db en tu sdcard lo guardas como .sql, si quieres hacer un respaldo debes de guardar el mismo tipo de dato.

Answer (score 2):

La solución es simple, estás abriendo el archivo seguramente con un editor de texto plano, los archivos *.db no son en texto plano. Te sugiero utilizar el addon de firefox "SQlite Manager" y abrirlo.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

No te olvides de este permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></u‌​ses-permission>
```

Mejorando un poco el código sería:

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        File db = new File(data, "//data//x.x.x//databases//xxx.db");
        File backup = new File(sd, "xxx.db");

        if (db.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(db).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backup).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Y no olvides los "RuntimePermissions" de Android Marshmallow, si no solicitas permiso para escribir en la SD el fichero no se creará si el dispositivo utiliza Android 6.0 o superior. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @AlbertoMéndez